# Calling a method of a seperate class into another class

Tags: java, methods, symbols, identifier, inventory

This small method is part of a very large program with many separate classes. The method below is meant to call in a portion of my Purchase class which keeps track of how much inventory is bought. However, although I have instantiated as follows above

```
 Purchase currentPurchase;
```

I continue to receive the errors "identifier is expected", and "cannot find symbol".

Method:

```
public double processPurchase(currentPurchase){

lemonsBought = currentPurchase.getNumLemonsBought();
iceBought = currentPurchase.getNumLemonsBought();
    cupsBought = currentPurchase.getNumCupsBought();
    sugarBought = currentPurchase.getNumSugarBought();

     lemonInventory += lemonsBought;
     iceInventory += iceBought;
     cupInventory += cupsBought;
     sugarInventory += sugarBought;
     money -= (.5 * lemonsBought) + (2 * iceBought) + (2 * cupsBought) + (0.25 * sugarBought);

    return currentPurchase;
 }
```

*Money is a separate pre-instantiated variable*

Comment: Where do you put the line "Purchase currentPurchase;"? Is "currentPurchase" a field of your Purchase class? If so, you don't need to specify it again as a parameter of the instance method "processPurchase".

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the identifier to your function or else the java compiler will not know what it should be receiving.

```
public double processPurchase(Purchase currentPurchase){
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are returning a wrong variable currentPurchase which u have passed as an argument and I you have't even manipulated it .R u sure u need this variable or money which is a double variable as well.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.